# Is JUnit's maximum timeout 15 minutes

Tags: maven, junit

I have one test which will last for a long time. And it would always timeout at around 15 minutes when I run it using maven even when I set the timeout as 30 minutes. But I can run the test successfully in eclipse. So I am wondering whether Junit's maximum timeout 15 minutes, is there any way to increase timeout to more than 15 minutes ?

Comment: If it last for 15 minutes, I strongly doubt it's a *unit* test... So maybe JUnit isn't the appropriate choice?

Comment: A JUnit test should be short and should not load database or Spring context. To make long tests use integration test. Uses the Maven Failsafe Plugin for integration tests. Property: `failsafe.timeout`

Comment: Interesting. I also have a strange timeout after 15 minutes. It times out exactly at 15 minutes, if the build is long, but doesn't time out if the test part is too long.